# Required sample size to hit certain subset of a ground set

Tags: ds.algorithms, pr.probability, randomized-algorithms

Suppose $X$ is a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $N_1,\cdots,N_k$ are k disjoint (unknown)subsets of $X$. There is a probability distribution $\phi$ on $X$ defined as $\phi(p) = \frac{\lvert\lvert p\rvert\rvert}{\sum_{q\in X}\lvert\lvert q\rvert\rvert}$. We sample points from $X$ according to this distribution. Moreover we also asume that $\phi(\cup_{i=1}^k N_i) > 1/2$. So a point sampled from $X$ would likely to be in $\cup_{i=1}^k N_i$. Suppose we sample $s$ points from $X$ according to $\phi$. Let $R=\{ r_1,\cdots,r_s\}$ be the sample. Define the event $\mathcal{E}_s\equiv \forall\lambda\in[k],\exists s_\lambda\in[s] s.t. r_{s_\lambda}\in N_\lambda$. So if the event $\mathcal{E}_s$ occurs, the sample has at least one point from every subset.

What is the required sample size $s$ so that $\mathcal{E}_s$ occurs with failure probability at most $\delta$?

Note that if $k=1$, then the situation is quite simple. We need roughly $\log(\frac{1}{\delta})$ samples so that the sample contains at least one point from $N_1$ with probability at least $1-\delta$.

This seems like an instance of hitting set problem. The motivation comes from [this](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611973075.53) paper, section 5.
Are there any general procedure that can be applied to this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some particular asymptotics in mind? It sounds like you're happy with the approximation $\log(1/\delta)$ for $k=1$. If you are letting $\delta\to0$ and keeping everything else fixed, then the answer is still $\log(1/\delta)$ for any given $k$ (by the union bound, it's enough to reduce the probability of missing each $N_i$ to $\delta/k$). If you want to consider $k\to\infty$ and $\delta\to0$ at the same time, or something similar, the answer can get more complicated. "Coupon collector with unequal probabilities" gets quite a few google hits, that could be a good place to start.

Comment: My hope is that the required sample size is independent of size of $X$, and polynomial in $k$ and $1/\delta$. By my assumption, there is a subset $N_\lambda$ such that $\phi(N_\lambda)>1/2k$. So roughly $k\log(1/\delta)$ samples are required to pick a point from $N_\lambda$. The problem is that there may be subsets with low probability mass.

Comment: It's not bounded, is it?  The probability of choosing a point in the union of the $N_i$'s is at least one half, but that doesn't preclude the probability of choosing a point in a given $N_i$ from being very small.  E.g. consider $d=1$, $n=k=2$ and $N_1 = \{0\}$, $N_2 = \{1\}$, $X=\{0,1\}$, so $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(1) = 1$.  Even if you sample forever you will never hit $N_1$.  What am I missing?  (Or what do you mean "occurs with failure probability at most $\delta$"?  I assume you mean, "occurs with probability at least $1-\delta$.")

Comment: @NealYoung , thanks for pointing that out. Yes the probability can be arbitrarily small. But suppose that none the probabilty is zero. In that case can there be a bound on the sample size that is indepenedent of $n$ and $d$?

Comment: Consider replacing 0 and 1 with $\epsilon$ and $1-\epsilon$ for an arbitrarily small $\epsilon>0$ in the previous example.  Then $\phi(\epsilon)=\epsilon$ and $\phi(1-\epsilon)=1-\epsilon$.  Then you need about $k$ rounds where $(1-\epsilon)^k \approx 1-\delta$, i.e. $k\approx \delta/\epsilon$.  So you can't have an upper bound that's independent of $\min_i \phi(N_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have figured it out.

Define $I=\{\lambda\in [k] : \phi(N_\lambda) < \frac{1}{4k}\}$ and $J=[k]\setminus I$. Both the size of $I$ and $J$ is at most k.

Define the event $\mathcal{E}_{(\lambda)}=\exists$ and index $s_\lambda$ such that $r_{s_\lambda}\in N_\lambda$. Clearly $\mathcal{E_s} = \cap_{\lambda\in[k]} \mathcal{E}_{(\lambda)}$.

Hence

$Pr[\mathcal{E_s}] = Pr[\cap_{\lambda\in[k]} \mathcal{E}_{(\lambda)}] = 1- Pr[\cup_{\lambda\in[k]} \bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}] \geq 1 - \sum_{\lambda\in[k]}Pr[\bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}] = 1 - \sum_{\lambda\in I}Pr[\bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}] - \sum_{\lambda\in J}Pr[\bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}]$.

The second to last inequality is due to union bound. Now we do case analysis. Note that the event $\bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}$ is equivalent to saying that $R$ does not contain any point from $N_\lambda$.

**Case I : $\lambda\in I$**

In this case $Pr[\bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}] = (1-\phi(N_\lambda))^s\leq exp(-s\phi(N_\lambda))$.
So if $s\geq \frac{1}{\phi(N_\lambda)}\ln(\frac{2m_1}{\delta})\geq 4k\ln(\frac{2}{\delta})$, we have $Pr[\bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}] \leq \frac{\delta}{2m_1}$. Note that we can assume that $m_1\geq 1$, otherwise this case does not occur.

**Case II: $\lambda\in J$**

In this case $Pr[\bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}]\leq (1-\frac{1}{4k})^s \leq exp(-\frac{s}{4k})$. Hence

$\sum_{\lambda\in J}Pr[\bar{\mathcal{E}}_{(\lambda)}]\leq m_2.exp(-\frac{s}{4k})\leq k.exp(-\frac{s}{4k})\leq \frac{\delta}{2}$ if $s\geq 4k\ln(\frac{2k}{\delta})$.

Combining the two cases, we have if $s=Ck\ln(\frac{2k}{\delta})$, for some sufficiently large contant $C>0$, we have $Pr[\mathcal{E}_s]\geq 1-\delta$.

Please if anybody goes through the proof, mention any error that may have incurred.

Thank you.

**P.S.** A thousand apologies for poor formatting.

Comment: Doesn't Case 1 have an error?  Note that $\phi(N_\lambda) \ln(2m_1/\delta)$ can be arbitrarily large (even infinite), so it's not enough to have $s\ge 4k\ln(2/\delta)$.  Aren't you using the inequality in the wrong direction?  (Also, minor comment: what is $m_1$?)

Comment: @NealYoung, yes I think that might be the problem with this arguement. $m_1$ and $m_1$ be the size of $I$and $J$. Can this even be done so that the sample size if indepenedent of $n$ and $d$? The point is that it works for $k=1$.

Comment: I don't think so, see my comment above following your post.